# Error: Objects are not valid as a React child when using axios to get API

Tags: reactjs

I am having problem with getting API with axios:
I'm getting this error from my page

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys
> {count, next, previous, results}). If you meant to render a collection
> of children, use an array instead.

here is my `Api.jsx`:

```
import React,{ useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import axios from 'axios';



const PokemonAPI = props => {
    // Get API
    const [responseData, setResponseData] = useState(null);
    const buttonAPI = useEffect(()=>{
        axios.get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?offset=0&limit=807")
        .then(res=>{setResponseData(res.data)})
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    }, []); 


    return(
        <div>
            <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={buttonAPI}>
                Get Pokemon
            </button>
        {
            responseData?.results.map((pokemon, i) => {
                return <p key={i}>{i + 1} {pokemon.name}</p>
                })
        }
    </div>
    )
}

export default PokemonAPI;
```

this is what I got from Components on browser:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`response.data` is an object in the case above. If you want to render the API response as is you have to `stringyfy` the data first, because objects are not valid React child.

The example below will render the response as a string.

```js
<div>
   {JSON.stringify(responseData, null ,4)}
</div>
```

If you meant to render each element in `results` array from the API response, you can use `Array.prototype.map`, for example

```
<div>
{
  responseData?.results.length && responseData.results.map(el => {
      return <p>{el.name}</p>
  })
}
</div>
```

***Note-*** `responseData` is initialized as `null` and gets populated with the API response after the component has mounted that is why you to check if the property `results` exists before trying to iterate over `responseData.results` otherwise it will result in an error (i.e `responseData.results` is undefined)

Comment: Hey Thanks for helping me out! That really solved my problem but can I add the button like when I click the button it will appear the pokemon name instead of show it all out

Comment: @nathannewyen if you want the API call to happen on a button click you should create a function and pass it as `onClick` to the button. Have a look at the [example codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-smoke-8kmji?file=/src/index.js).

Comment: And shouldn't assign the `useEffect` call to some variable. If you are looking for a way to memoize the function that makes the fetch call [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div>
 {JSON.stringify(responseData)}
</div>
```

Comment: Can I use .map() to get items out of the json file?

Comment: Yes, I guess other answers have explained you how.

Answer (score 1):

Hitting the api above, I get the following response.

```
{
    "count": 964,
    "next": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?offset=50&limit=50",
    "previous": null,
    "results": [{...}, {...}],
}
```

You are rendering this directly, however, this is not valid JSX.
If you want to render the `results`, you need to map over the `results` array and convert it to valid JSX. Here is an example.

```
const PokemonAPI = props => {

        // Get API
        const [responseData, setResponseData] = useState({});
        const { results = [] } = responseData;
        const validJSX = results.map(result => (
          <>
            <div>Name: {results.name}</div>
            <div>URL: {result.url}</div>
          </>
        ));
        useEffect(()=>{
            axios.get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?offset=0&limit=50")
                .then(response=>{setResponseData(response.data)})
        }, []); 
    
        return(
            <div>
                {validJSX}
            </div>
        )
    }

export default PokemonAPI;
```

Comment: im getting this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

Comment: should be `responseData.results || []`

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can iterate

```
export default function App() {
  const [responseData, setResponseData] = React.useState(null);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?offset=0&limit=50")
      .then(response => {
        setResponseData(response.data);
      });
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {responseData&&responseData.results.map(result => (
        <div key={result.url}>{result.name}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

You are saving response of API which is an object.
to iterate your array use **responseData.results(array)**;